# Enviar dados de formulário por Ajax em projeto MVC

Tags: php, ajax, mvc

Para começar vou exemplificar um pouco do sistema para vocês, minha estrutura de diretórios é a seguinte:

```
>leganto(raiz)
---> controller
-------> ControllerGlobal.php
-------> OutrosControllesDeObjetos

---> model
-------> ModelDeObjetos

---> view
-------> objeto
-----------> CRUDdeCadaObjeto

---> libs
---> css
---> imgs
---> js

---> ajax
-------> arquivosDeRequisicaoAjax

---> index.php
```

Apenas as camadas Controller e Model são orientadas e a View é estruturada.

Uso url amigáveis onde tenho de 1 a 3 parâmetros na url, posso ter url da seguinte maneira:

- site/ato
- site/objeto/ato
- site/objeto/ato/id

Resumidamente, ato seria meu método, objeto minha classe e id é usado para quando quero exibir um registro do banco. Ou seja, na tela de registro irei ter o link:

```
site/account/create //vai instânciar o controller account e executar seu método create
```

Todo o fluxo da aplicação é iniciado no `index.php`, nele eu instâncio o meu `ControllerGlobal` e chamo seu método `request`que pega o `objeto` e `ato` da url e instância o `controller` daquele `objeto`  executando o `método` referente ao `ato` pego pela url.

Vamos ao problema, tenho a view de cadastro que é chamada sempre que a url é `site/account/create`, a url faz o `CrontrollerGlobal` executar esse código (que é o método create do meu controller de account):

```
private function create()
{
    $title = "Registre-se no Leganto"; // titulo da página
    $icon = "plus"; // icone da página

    // quando o formulário de cadastro for enviado, com token de proteção
    if(isset($_POST['userinsertrequest']) and $_POST['userinsertrequest'] == $_SESSION['token'])
    {
        try
        {
            $user = array(); // cria array com dados
            foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
            {
                $user[$key] = addslashes(htmlentities($value));
            }
            // chama model que faz o insert
            $insert = $this->model->prepareNewUser($user);
            if($insert)
            {
                // se registrou volta pra tela de login
                header("Location:{$_SESSION['self']}");
            }
            else
            {   // se não fala que houve um erro desconhecido
                $error = "Houve um error ao gravar o usuário.";
            }
        }
        catch(Exception $ex)
        {   // pega erro de validação de dados do model
            $error = $ex->getMessage();
        }
    }

    // inclui meu view de cadastro
    include 'view/account/user-create.php';
}
```

Quero inserir os dados do meu `formulário` de cadastro no `$_POST` e executar essa função acima para realizar o cadastro, isso com o AJAX para não ter a perca dos dados digitados. Tentei da seguinte forma:

```
$(function()
{
    // quando meu formulário for submetido
    $("form[name = fm-register-user]").submit(function()
    {
        alert("ENVIOU"); // alerta funcionou
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "account/create", // tenta requisitar a função de criar
            data: { // pego meus dados incluindo o token
                name:               $("input[name = name]").val(),
                email :             $("input[name = email]").val(),
                date :              $("input[name = date]").val(),
                username :          $("input[name = username]").val(),
                password :          $("input[name = password]").val(),
                confirmpassword :   $("input[name = confirmpassword]").val(),
                ocupation :         $("input[name = ocupation]").val(),
                history :           $("input[name = history]").val(),
                userinsertrequest : $("input[name = userinsertrequest]").val()
            } ,
            success: function(retorno) {
                alert(retorno); // dou alerta na minha mensagem de retorno

            }
        });
    });
});
```

De proposito eu deixei um erro no meu insert no banco de dados para testar e ver se o erro era exibido no alert, mas quando eu submeto o formulário só é exibido o alert de `"ENVIOU"`.

Minha view está da seguinte forma:

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Leonardo Vilarinho
 * Date: 10/03/2016
 * Time: 14:51
*/

$printError = (isset($error))
    ? "<div class='text-danger text-center'><strong>{$error}</strong></div>"
    : "";

$_SESSION['token'] = md5(time());
$_SESSION['title'] = (!empty($title)) ? $title : "";
/*
  "usuarios",
                    array("username", "email", "password",
                        "image", "name", "date",
                        "ocupation", "history", "active", "token"),
 * */
?>
    <section class="row">

        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <div class="panel panel-success">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">
                        <i class="fa fa-<?php echo (!empty($icon)) ? $icon : ""; ?>"></i>
                        <?php echo (!empty($title)) ? $title : ""; ?>
                    </h3>
                </div>
                <?php echo $printError; ?>

                <form method="post" name="fm-register-user">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <table class="table form-group-sm">
                            <tr class="text-center text-muted">
                                <td colspan="10">
                                    <input name="image" type="file" accept=".jpg, .png">
                                    <img src="<?php echo $_SESSION['self'] ?>imgs/cover.jpg" style="width: 100px;" class="img-circle profile">
                                    <p>Foto do Perfil</p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="1">Nome Completo:</td>
                                <td colspan="9">
                                    <input name="name" maxlength="255" required  placeholder="Nome Completo" type="text" class="form-control"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="1">Email:</td>
                                <td colspan="7">
                                    <input name="email" maxlength="200" required  placeholder="Email" type="email" class="form-control email validar-email"/>
                                </td>
                                <td colspan="1">Nascimento:</td>
                                <td colspan="1">
                                    <input name="date" required type="date" class="form-control"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="1">Usuário:</td>
                                <td colspan="5">
                                    <input name="username" maxlength="20" required  placeholder="Usuário" type="text" class="form-control"/>
                                </td>
                                <td colspan="4" class="text-muted">
                                    <p>(Sem espaços e acentos.)</p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="1">
                                    Senha:
                                </td>
                                <td colspan="7">
                                    <input name="password" maxlength="15" id="senha" required placeholder="Senha" type="password" class="form-control" />
                                </td>
                                <td colspan="1" class="confirm">
                                    Senha:
                                </td>
                                <td colspan="1" class="confirm">
                                    <input name="comfirmpassword" maxlength="15" id="senha2" required placeholder="Confirmar Senha" type="password" class="form-control" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="10">
                                    <div class="barprogress text-center" style="color: white; border: 1px solid #b4b5b2;">
                                        <div>.</div>
                                    </div
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="1">Ocupação:</td>
                                <td colspan="9">
                                    <input name="ocupation" maxlength="255" required placeholder="Ocupação" type="text" class="form-control" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="1">Sobre:</td>
                                <td colspan="9">
                                    <textarea placeholder="Conte-nos sua história..." maxlength="255" name="history" required class="form-control"></textarea>
                                    <div class="text-right count">
                                        <p>0 / 255</p>
                                    </div>

                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <input name="userinsertrequest" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['token']; ?>" type="hidden" />

                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-footer text-center">
                        <a class="btn btn-danger" href="<?php echo $_SESSION['self']; ?>" >Cancelar</a>
                        <input value="Criar" type="submit" class="btn btn-success" />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

<?php
$_SESSION['scripts'] = "<script src='{$_SESSION['self']}libs/formzin.js'></script>";
$_SESSION['scripts'] .= "<script src='{$_SESSION['self']}js/verify-password.js'></script>";
$_SESSION['scripts'] .= "<script src='{$_SESSION['self']}js/profile-inputs.js'></script>";
$_SESSION['scripts'] .= "<script src='{$_SESSION['self']}ajax/register-user.js'></script>";
```

Na teoria acho que o ajax está correto mas não está funcionando. Não sei se é porque os erros da camada model são `Exceptions`, pois não sei se o Ajax capta `Exceptions` como retorno.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Tenha em mente que MVC não é uma tecnologia, é apenas uma maneira de se fazer as coisas, o seu problema parece com a rota.

Então o Ajax nada mais que é uma requisição em "background" rodando sobre uma API do Javascript, se usar a url assim no brower `account/create` e funciona então deveria funcionar no ajax, resumindo eu suspeito que a url aonde se encontra a chamada ajax, por exemplo `http://localhost/projeto/exemplo/` ao executar o ajax assim:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "account/create",
```

Vai interpretar assim `http://localhost/projeto/exemplo/account/create`, mas entendo que na verdade o desejado seria isto `http://localhost/projeto/account/create`, o que você pode tentar então é isto:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../account/create",
```

Uma dica, sempre adicione o `error` no `$.ajax` pra detectar problemas, por exemplo:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "account/create",
    data: {
        name:               $("input[name = name]").val(),
        email :             $("input[name = email]").val(),
        date :              $("input[name = date]").val(),
        username :          $("input[name = username]").val(),
        password :          $("input[name = password]").val(),
        confirmpassword :   $("input[name = confirmpassword]").val(),
        ocupation :         $("input[name = ocupation]").val(),
        history :           $("input[name = history]").val(),
        userinsertrequest : $("input[name = userinsertrequest]").val()
    } ,
    success: function(retorno) {
        alert(retorno); // dou alerta na minha mensagem de retorno

    } ,
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        console.log(status, error);//Captura o erro e envia ao console
    }
});
```

Uma dica de PHP, é que quando usar `location:` é preferivel não enviar nada pro output, então faça isso:

```
if($insert)
{
    // se registrou volta pra tela de login
    header("Location:{$_SESSION['self']}");
    exit;
}
```

Só não use o `exit;` acaso precise executar algo a mais "depois" após o `location`.

Comment: Realmente esqueci do `exit` geralmente eu coloco ele bem no final daquela parte do projeto mesmo. E pode mesmo ser o url citado no Ajax, vou tentar com o `../`, mas seria legal colocar um `<?php echo $_SESSION['self']; ?>`? Essa variável é o link do site (pego do servidor)

Comment: Desconheço o `$_SESSION['self']`, é nativo do seu framework? é equivalente ao `$_SESSION['REQUEST_URI']`? @lvcs

Comment: Sim sim é o `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

Comment: @lvcs olhando assim, vai ser o mesmo que que usar apenas `account/create`, ou seja não vai resolver :/ - Testa o `error: function` e me diz o que acontece

Comment: Colocando o `../` funcionou, mas pelo jeito o método que estou usando não é funcional com o ajax.. pois ao dar submit no formulário automaticamente ele recarrega a página..

Comment: O jeito vai ser tentar clicar uma classe só para essas requisições AJAX ou mudar a estrutura toda do MVC.

Comment: @lvcs não precisa mudar a estrutura, eu acho que você poderia criar uma variavel global que tenha o root do teu projeto, o que acha?

Comment: O problema não está sendo esse rs, como estou requerindo a função create no ajax ele está dando echo em partes do meu template e atrapalhando o resultado do Ajax.. Então a ideia seria criar um controller personalizado pro ajax

Comment: @lvcs mas da maneira que fala parece que você quer misturar o back-end com o front-end, se entendi. O seu Ajax carrega uma página HTML ou ele trás um resultado json?

Comment: Atualmente ele está executando aquela função create do controller que citei na pergunta, pensei que assim funcionaria.. Estou é mais com dificuldade de implementar AJAX ele no MVC pois estou acostumado só chamar um arquivo estruturado (um script mesmo) no AJAX.

Comment: @lvcs mas então é como eu disse MVC não é tecnologia, as pessoas confundem muito isso, o seu problemas são as rotas e a resposta, na verdade o ajax nada mais que é uma requisição em background, você pode pegar a resposta dele ou não é totalmente opcional. Olha prometo que vou reler a sua pergunta e vou editar a resposta amanhã (tenho que sair), mas só me responde uma coisa, o que você quer é poder chamar o ajax de qualquer nivel de path na rota? ...

Comment: @lvcs ... Ao menos foi o que entendi do problema, por exemplo mesmo que você a sua página seja esta `http://localhost/projeto/a/b/c/d/e/f/` e o ajax chama isso `action/teste/` ele sempre deve reconhecer como o root do projeto é isso? Porque se for eu tenho uma ideia pra implementar, mas preciso sabe se você tem um arquivo "global", pois poderia adicionar nele uma constante =)

Comment: O problema não é o caminho que o ajax vai buscar mas sim que a estrutura minha do MVC está 'sujando' o retorno do ajax com html.. pois no meio da rota eu dou echo no template etc.

Comment: Então eu acho que o meu primeiro comentário foi o problema, você sabe que o ajax do jQuery envia um header customizado né? com ele é possivel detectar se é ajax, tipo criar um método chamado `isXhr` e prevenir o envio do template acaso a chamada seja ajax, poderia dar uma alternativa json =) @lvcs amanhã continuamos, me chama no chat as 14:00 se puder

Comment: Você estava certo, não sabia do header com Ajax, pesquisei aqui e editei onde estava exibindo meu template e funcionou. Valeu!!

Comment: @Lvcs que bom que deu certo =)